# Getting ASPX Links to inherit the Browsers current HTTP Method (HTTP VS HTTPS

Tags: asp.net

I am very new to this site so if I posted something wrong, please advise.

I am not a web developer--I cannot overstate this, but I am working to convert our internal sites to use HTTPS.

All Links are being converted to a type that will inherit the current browsing sessions http mode, so instead of specifying http or HTTPS we specify //internalsite/stuff in our Href Links, and such seems to have worked. I am doing this because I want to be able to convert back effortlessly (We have 20gb of aspx/cs/html files!, Ideally by just re-adding the port 80 binding and removing the HTTPS re-write. This is working marvelously except for one thing, aspx.cs files. Any time I reference a file using the ASPX.cs files the file attempts to load via http and thusly fails since port 80 isn't active and because its mixed content.

Is there a way to write a url in aspx.cs files that inherit the current browser mode (HTTP or HTTPS), and do it in such a way that does not require me to write http/HTTPS in the link? As it is right now, Sections like `"startOver.HRef = "tsViewer.aspx?coid=" + coID;"` seem to always load in http, even though the source calling file is in https...

Please inform me if I did not explain that clearly.

Comment: `Sections like "startOver.HRef = "tsViewer.aspx?coid=" + coID;" seem to always load in http, even though the source calling file is in https...` -- are you sure this is happening and that's there is no other code interfering? I have been doing this for years and it works perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The **HttpRequest** class has a property that will tell you if the request came from http or https.

**IsSecureConnection** in .Net Framework:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?view=netframework-4.8

**IsHttps** in .Net Core
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-5.0

You should be able to get the **HttpRequest** off the **HttpContext** of the request.

After that it is a matter of getting the connection type over into your asp.net page to set the hyperlinks to match.